# Excel Chart: multiple datasets having significantly different numbers of digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to show a comparison between number of orders and dollars of shipment track against the cost.
I want to make a chart using this data, however, the numbers have huge differences to put them into one chart.

What is the right chart for this data?
I tried to add secondary axis, but even though I did that, the number difference is huge so it did not make any difference.
I also tried to divide the Dollars values by 100 or 1000, however it is hard to show the orders numbers.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6sNo.png)

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTnnR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to try to illustrate data with very large and very small values is to actually use two charts. One chart shows all values in full, so you can see that the small values are very small compared to the large values. The other chart is scaled to allow the smaller values to be compared to each other, with the large values going up to and way beyond the top of the chart. You can try to play with gradients to make the large values seem to disappear into the clouds.

Secondary axis are tough, because people don't get them, and they mess with our built-in precognitive abilities to judge the heights of bars in a chart.

[image]

Comment: I agree with your idea. Since the values' difference is huge, it is hard to show the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the secondary axis for Order number and add the lable for your series.

- First I convert Cost and Dollars values in millions via formulas.
- Then create a combo chart with a secondary axis.
  [image]
- For units of the vertical axis, Major is "0.1", you can set the values you want, and I removed the vertical axis and the secondary one.
- At last, I add the laber for each series, and adjusted positions for some labels.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas. I used your idea to create the graph since it is what I needed to create.